# $\exists x ~ \forall y ~ f(x, y) \iff \forall y() ~ \exists x~ f(x, y(x))$ Name? Proof?

Tags: logic, axioms, higher-order-logic

I was looking at potential theorems, and this one came up:

> $$\bigg(\exists x ~ \forall y ~:~ f(x, y) \bigg) \iff \bigg(\forall y() ~ \exists x ~:~ f(x, y(x))\bigg)$$
>
> (where the second $y$ is being quantified over all total unary functions)

Does this proposition have a name?  It is a generalization of

$$(a_{00} \land a_{01}) \lor (a_{10} \land a_{11}) \iff (a_{00} \lor a_{10}) \land (a_{00} \lor a_{11}) \land (a_{01} \lor a_{10}) \land (a_{01} \lor a_{11})$$

I'm not even sure which higher order axioms I would use to prove it.  Any references or suggestions for proofs or criticisms of the theorem are welcome.

Comment: Why use the same symbol for two different types? Just like making your life difficult?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Was doing it to make the reversal of quantifier but non-reversal of parameter more obvious.  A design maxim is to name variables after their purpose rather than after their type.  That's the naming convention I tend to follow.  Sorry if it is troublesome~

Comment: The theorem fails if the domain for $x$ and $y$ is empty.

Comment: @JanStout If the universe is empty, then the left side is clearly false.  The right side, only 1 function exists which is the empty set, and since no x exists in the domain of the empty set it would seem the right side is false also.  Do you disagree?  I guess it depends on your axiomization, if a function can exist in an empty universe.

Comment: Existensial quantification over an empty domain is indeed false, however, universal quantification over an empty domain is true: all members of the empty set satisfy whatever predicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the dual statement:
$$
\forall x \exists y\, R(x,y) \iff \exists f \forall x\, R(x, f(x)).
$$
(I've used more typical variables in stating it; no good purpose is served by using "$y$" as a variable for two different sorts of things.) This is essentially the Axiom of Choice (AC), and is provable using AC. $f$ is called a *uniformizing* function for $R$. If further constraints are placed on $R$ and $f$ (such as, "$R, f$ are $\Pi^1_1$", or "$R, f$ are projective"), it may or may not hold in a theory (and may or may not be provable even in ZFC). See the wikipedia article on [uniformization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_%28set_theory%29) for more.

Comment: Ah it is essentially the axiom of choice, seems obvious in hindsight but I'm too used to seeing it written with set notation.  The link says it is weaker though.  Is it only because the link is dealing with "Polish Spaces", or is there another reason for the discrepancy?

Comment: Read the article more closely. It does say that if no restrictions are placed on $R$, or on its domain & range, then the principle is just AC. Which is clear in any case: if $Y$ is a set of nonempty sets, let $R(x,y)\iff (x\in y \land y\in Y)$; then $\forall x \exists y R(x,y)$, and a function $f$ that uniformizes $R$ is just a choice function for $Y$. The "uniformization" terminology is usually in more restricted contexts than for arbirtrary sets — most often in descriptive set theory, where domains and ranges are typically Polish spaces.

Comment: @DanielV: It depends significantly on what your "unary function" means. If it means the ZFC kind of function (i.e. encoded as a set), **and** the quantifiers are **restricted to** a set, then this is exactly the axiom of choice. Namely, AC is equivalent to $∀S\ ( ∀x{∈}S\ ∃y\ ( R(x,y) ) ⇔ ∃f{∈}Func(S)\ ∀x{∈}S ( R(x,f(x)) ) )$ over ZF (by first using replacement to bound $y$). But if there is no restriction on $x$, then it is simply false, because $∀x\ ∃y\ (x=y)$ but there is no function with domain $V$. But ZFC plus global choice gives you something like it for unrestricted $x$.

Answer (score 2):

The dual of this (particularly in the context of automated theorem-proving), which results in a $\exists\forall$ formula is called Skolemization or conversion to [Skolem Normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form). As pointed out in a comment, the formulation as in the question that leads to $\forall\exists$ formula is often called [Herbrandization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrandization).

I find Skolemisation more intuitive than Herbrandization: in Skolemisation, you are looking at a string of quantifiers and analysing the dependencies of possible witnesses for the existentially quantified variables. E.g., given, $\forall a\forall b\exists c \forall d \exists e P(a, b, c, d, e)$, $c$ may depend on $a$ and $b$ while $e$ may depend on $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. Expressing the existentially quantified variables as functions of the values on which they may depend allows you to move the existentials to the front, turning

$$\forall a\forall b\exists c \forall d \exists e P(a, b, c, d, e) $$

into

$$\exists c\exists d\forall a\forall b\forall c P(a, b, c(a, b), d, e(a, b, c(a, b))).$$

These are equivalent in higher-order logic given the axiom of choice.

Comment: As the questioner, I found this answer useful even though he was addressing the dual.  My only issue is in the specifics of Skolemization (or the dual), how the unquantified functions are interpreted.  Most of the definitions of Skolemization I have seen in the past leave that a bit vague, which is why I didn't recognize the connection before this answer.

Comment: I am glad you found this answer useful. I have fixed it in the light of Carl Mummert's comment. My mistake was to look at the formula in BrianO's answer rather than the one in your actual question and then to provide you with what I hoped would be a useful supplement to that answer. Thanks as always to downvoters for their open and constructive criticism.

Answer (score 1):

The transformation
$$
(\exists x)(\forall y) \phi(x,y) \Longrightarrow (\forall f)(\exists x)\phi(x, f(x))
$$
is a special case of a process called *Herbrandization*. This is dual to the more well known operation of *Skolemization*. Indeed, if you know what Skolemization is then Herbrandization can be defined as the negation of the Skolemization of the negation of the prenex form a formula:

- Original in prenex form: $( \exists x)(\forall y) \phi(x,y) $
- Negation: $(\forall x)(\exists y)\lnot \phi(x,y)$
- Skolemization of negation: $(\exists f)(\forall x) \lnot \phi(x, f(x))$, or $(\forall x)\lnot \phi(x, f(x))$ if we drop the function quantifier.
- Herbrandization (negation of previous): $(\forall f)(\exists x)\phi(x, f(x))$ or $(\exists x)\phi(x,f(x))$ if we drop the function quantifier.

The Skolemization of a formula may not be equivalent to the original formula, in general, and the same holds for Herbrandization. In general, Skolemization preserves satisfiability, and Herbrandization preserves validity. Precisely: if we drop the quantifier on the function $f$ and instead make it a new symbol in the language, the original formula is valid if and only if its Herbrandization is valid, while the original formula is satisfiable if and only if its Skolemization is satisfiable.
In this way we can reduce the question of satisfiability of arbitrary formulas to the question of satisfiability of purely universal prenex formulas, and the question of validity to the question of validity for purely existential prenex formulas.

Herbrandization is a key method in [Herbrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand%27s_theorem). Also see [this answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/114103/5442).